# How can I get my unsocialized cat into the carrier to be spayed?

Tags: cats, socializing, desexing

12 weeks ago I bought a British short hair cat. I saw her in a cattery at breeders cattery at bottom of garden, well l think I did but the cat she  was cuddling and kissing was a lot bigger. When i got home my friend got her out of the carrier and she ran into my bedroom were she still is spending a lot of time. Since then I have got her to stop hiding all the time and spends time with me.

I have had a few cats but always got them neutered. But this time I cannot get close to pick her up to put her in the carrier. I have put food and treats in it but she still does not get into the carrier.

I am disabled and walking is a problem so I can't get around well. She won't let me stroke or pick her up. Other people have tried to get her picked up but its impossible so there is no way I can take her to the vet.

Also vet will only do it out of heat. She had the first heat for just a week then a week and half she is in heat again and is louder and its going to be longer. I talk to her when she is yowling and that shuts her up a bit.

When she is in heat, it stops me trying to get close to her and sometimes she is getting her terrified look that she had at first. I don't want her to be like she was, but its getting me down that everything is against her getting her fixed.

How can I get her to calm down and get her into the carrier so I can get her spayed?

Comment: Have you spoken to the breeder? They sometimes help in getting the cat socialized and settled into their new homes.

Answer (score 2):

Leave the carrier out with a blanket or towel in it, with the door open. Cats tend to enjoy lounging in them once they stop seeing them solely as vehicles to trips to the vet.

As for calming her down, food is God when it comes to cats; start by feeding her near you, then leave a trail to you once she is comfortable with that.  Keep moving the food trail closer until eventually she is comfortable with eating near you.  Eventually you'll have her eating from your hand.

It also helps to play with your cat in closer quarters; get a feather toy (on a stick) and get her jumping around.

Comment: In other words, socialize the cat. If you can't, you're stuck with treating her as a semi-feral and using wrapping techniques, or trying scruffing her (which causes some cats to stop struggling -- the "feline pause button"). Obviously, if your mobility is limited you may need to get assistance. Of course if she's an indoor-only cat you CAN wait until she has settled in before taking her to the vet.